# Does dealloc still get called?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

For my iOS 7 app, just want to confirm:

1. Does `dealloc` still get called?
2. Does it have something to do with whether ARC is enabled or not?

Comment: Yes and you could actually confirm that by logging something in your custom `dealloc` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `dealloc` *is* called when an object is deallocated, regardless of whether you are using ARC.

Note however, when you use ARC, you do not need to (in fact you cannot) call `[super dealloc]` from your implementation of `dealloc`, as ARC does this automatically.